# Prevent iFRame from reloading when an error occurs

Tags: javascript

I have successfully injected an iframe( its source is `https://google.com`)  to an HTML page  dom using vanilla js. But, there are a number of errors arising from injecting the iframe to the DOM.

The most common error is

```
crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
(anonymous) @ VM18962:7288
m=cdos,dpf,hsm,jsa,d,csi:3553 POST https://play.google.com/log?format=json&hasfast=true&authuser=0 400
```

But despite the error, if I am fast, I'm able to search for something on the google page being accessed by my iframe. however, less than a second later, right before it shows this error: `crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.`, the iframe RELOADS and goes back to the google homepage.

How do I stop the iframe from reloading or going to the previous page, despite the errors and warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google does not permit `https://google.com` to be loaded through an iframe. That's the ultimate reason for that error you're witnessing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/4542055